# GDM3 Login Screen on Ubuntu 18.04 not updating

Tags: 18.04

I am very much interested in changing the login screen of my 18.04 LTS (not the lock screen, the login screen) which is noise-texture.png. I followed this link 
[How do I change login screen purple color to another one or image (if possible) on Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990960/how-do-i-change-login-screen-purple-color-to-another-one-or-image-if-possible)
But doing like what this discussion said, I get a grayish lock screen which freezes on login. Although I am able to log in but there is no wallpaper on the login screen.
Please help.

Comment: which file did you change?

Comment: `/usr/share/gnome-shell/themes/gdm3.css` and the other one which is `ubuntu.css` got automatically changed.

Comment: can you share the contenet part which you edited in the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1086968/739431

Comment: @PRATAP I am doing the same thing, but my wallpaper is not visible in the login screen.

Comment: can you share the contenet in the file which you edited